# In Excel, how to verify that numbers from one cell in sheet 1, are the same with numbers in several columns in sheet 2?

Tags: excel, cell

I don't know what formula to use to verify that the numbers in one cell in sheet one are the same with numbers found in sheet 2 arranged in columns. I tried with `vlookup` but that works only if I search between cell to cell, rows to rows or columns to columns. Can i use a formula/several to find what data I am missing from one cell to several rows? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

=(COUNTIF(E2:E100,A1)>0)+0

instead of

=VLOOKUP(A1,E2:E100,0)

where A1 houses the lookup value and E2:E100 is the first column of the lookup table of interest. Adjust the ranges to suit.
(source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/10000-how-compare-value-list-values-see-if-fir.html)

I think this could help you too: https://superuser.com/a/601421